# Use RelativeLayout outside CoordinatorView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a `CoordinatorLayout`, in where a `RecyclerView` displays some CardViews, defined in an other layout. Under this scrollable view, i am trying to add a `RelativeLayout`, which inherits fields for text input, buttons for sending it, etc.

The problem: `CoordinatorLayout` seems to block the whole screen, although i told to wrap contents height. Nevertheless, RelativeLayout is added (tested it by setting Coordinator-height = 50dp), but off-screen. What is wrong here?

PS: I know how to solve it with `android:layout_weight=xx`. But thats not what i want to achieve, because it blocks my EditText to expand, if bigger texts are entered.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/data_coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/delete_data_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/data_coordinator_layout">

        <EditText/>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: in "data_coordinator_layout", dont u mean width=match and height=wrap ?

Comment: Yes, correct! As seen in layout.xml

Comment: sry i meant in "+id/delete_data_layout"

Comment: Because i can not see that RelativeLayout, i tried to force it showing up by matching height. Match AND wrap seem to work, but offscreen

Comment: ok, i understand now. Try to surround your CoordinatorLayout Inside a linear

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty simple. You need to align your Relative Layout (delete_data_layout) to bottom of your parent. Then you make the Coordinator layout above the Relative Layout. This causes, that Coordinator layout will always stay above the Relative Layout - even when the Edittext expands.

Here's the XML.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/data_coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/delete_data_layout">  <---- Change here

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/delete_data_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">   <---- Change here

        <EditText/>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```